# Is there a command in java to measure the execution time?

Tags: java, command-line, execution-time

Is there a command in java to measure the execution time ?

Something like

```
System.out.println(execution.time);
```

in the end of the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [complete and little modified example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0132.html) on how you could do that:

```
public class ExecutionTimer {
  private long start;
  private long end;

  public ExecutionTimer() {
    reset();
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public void end() {
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public long duration(){
    return (end-start);
  }

  public void reset() {
    start = 0;  
    end   = 0;
  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    // simple example
    ExecutionTimer t = new ExecutionTimer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++){
System.out.print(".");
}
    t.end();
    System.out.println("\n" + t.duration() + " ms");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd set `start` in the constructor, which makes it harder to use the class wrongly ;-)

Comment: I think there is no need for the reset method. Good example though.

Comment: Well, in theory, you should use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, because currentTimeMillis can go backwards (when the system time is changed). But it's not a real problem in most cases, as the system time rarely changes. nanoTime measures the elapsed time, so it is immune to system time changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily implement that yourself using [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29):

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
executeLongRunningTask();
final long durationInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
System.out.println("executeLongRunningTask() took " + durationInMilliseconds + "ms.");
```

Alternatively (especially if your task doesn't run as long), you might want to use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29). Note that contrary to how `currentTimeMillis()` works, the value returned by `nanoTime()` is **not** relative to some specified time. This means that `nanoTime()` can only be used to measure *time spans* and can't be used to identify some specifiy point in time.

Comment: It is better to use `System.nanoTime()` for measuring elapsed time.

Comment: @Péter: more often than not, the difference won't be noticeable. I was answering based on the assumption that execution time is somewhat long-ish (i.e. multiple seconds).

Answer (score 2):

You could  run a profiler, or use the difference of two calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Like this  :

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
....
doSomething();
....
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Execution time was "+(end-start)+" ms.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use System.currentTimeMillis() before and after the code executing.  Joda-Time has more sophisticated versions of that:  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more details on what you measure, I strongly suggest you use JMX especially ThreadMXBean : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html

Code sample :

```
ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
if (bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported()) {
    long cpuTime = bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime( );
}
long userTime = bean.getCurrentThreadUserTime( );
```

A quite complete explanation with code samples is available here : 
http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking

Answer (score 1):

Use the ThreadMXBean for more detailed timing:

```
public class Timer {

  static { 
    // needed to request 1ms timer interrupt period 
    // http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.642646.9
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);  (Windows NT)
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
      }
    });
    thread.setName("Timer");
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
  }

  private final ThreadMXBean threadMX = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
  private final long elapsedStart;
  private final long cpuStart;
  private final long userStart;

  public Timer() {
    cpuStart = threadMX.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
    userStart = threadMX.getCurrentThreadUserTime();
    elapsedStart = System.nanoTime();
  }

  public void times() {
    long elapsed = elapsedStart - System.nanoTime();
    long cpu = cpuStart - threadMX.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
    long user = userStart - threadMX.getCurrentThreadUserTime();
    System.out.printf("elapsed=%-8.3f cpu=%-8.3f user=%-8.3f [seconds]", 
            elapsed/1.0e9, cpu/1.0e9, user/1.0e9);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons library has [StopWatch](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) class and Spring also has [StopWatch](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can design a control abstraction `time` that takes as parameter an action to be performed and measures and prints the time required to execute it.

**Code:**

```
interface Action<A> {
  public A perform();
}

class Timer {
  public static <A> A time(final String description, final Action<A> action) {
    final long start = System.nanoTime();
    final A result = action.perform();
    final long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(description + " - Time elapsed: " + (end - start) +"ns");
    return result;
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int factorialOf5 = Timer.time("Calculating factorial of 5",
      new Action<Integer>() {
        public Integer perform() {
          int result = 1;
          for(int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
            result *= i;
          }
          return result;
        }
      }
    );
    System.out.println("Result: " + factorialOf5);
  }
}

// Output:
// Calculating factorial of 5 - Time elapsed: 782052ns
// Result: 120
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the class example of RoflcoptrException. 
I rewrote it to its essentials:

```
public class ExecutionTimer {
  private long start;

  public ExecutionTimer() {
    restart();
  }

  public void restart() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public long time(){
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (end-start);
  }
  public String toString() {
     return "Time="+time()+" ms";
  }
}
```